# JQGrid AltClass using JQuery UI Theme

Tags: jquery-ui, jqgrid

I'm trying to find a way to use an existing jquery ui class for my altclass or use a background image from a theme. My purpose for this is so that I don't have to edit my altclass every time I change the theme. Has anybody achieved this?

Comment: Which *standard existing*  class you think to use? The default value for `altclass` is `"ui-priority-secondary"`. It can looks not clear enough in some themes, but there are no alternatives in jQuery UI CSS Framework. See all classes in [the documentation](https://api.jqueryui.com/theming/css-framework/). You can set any other class from the list as the value of `altclass` and to see the results.

Comment: thanks. i'll look around. my prob with using `ui-priority-secondary` is that the 70%  opacity makes it difficult to read

Comment: I think so too, but there are **no standard existing classes** which exist in every jQuery UI Theme. I personally choose the color manually *for specific theme* which color is good to read.